# Is the nullset-indexed union of slices a nullset?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, product-space

Let $A$ be a Borel-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and denote by $A_t:=\{u\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \mid (t,u)\in A\}$ ($t\in\mathbb{R}$) the $t$-slices of $A$.

If $N$ is a Lebesgue nullset of $\mathbb{R}$, can we conclude that the subset

$$
A_N \, := \, \bigcup_{t\in N}(t,A_t) \quad \text{of } \ \ A
$$

is a Lebesgue nullset of $\mathbb{R}^n$? [If necessary, it may be assumed that $A$ is compact.]

(This is *not* a homework question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This easily follows from Fubini's theorem (or, even easier, from Tonelli's theorem).

Comment: Wouldn't your invocation of Fubini (or Tonelli) require the product measurability of $A_N$? (If so, how would you prove that?)

Comment: @fsp-b: A product of measurable sets is always measurable with respect to the product measure. $A_N$ is the intersection of $A$ with $N\times {\mathbf R}^{n-1}$.

Comment: @fsp-b: I mean, there is some subtlety there: there are two notions of measurability (belonging to the $\sigma$-algebra on which the measure is defined, and Carathedory measurability), if you define the Lebesgue measure on only the Borel sets. I think in some cases, the statement in my last comment may not be true (if by measurable you mean Caratheodory measurable) for some exotic spaces (I think $\sigma$-finiteness may play a role; you need it for Fubini/Tonelli anyway). I did not think about it much. Anyway, there are many ways to apply Fubini here without explicitly showing measurability.